# What does `go list` do in Go's toolset?

Tags: go

`go list` has some inconsistent behavior that I am having a difficult time understanding. When I enter the `go help list` command, it says:

```
usage: go list [-f format] [-json] [-m] [list flags] [build flags] [packages]

List lists the named packages, one per line.
```

This does not make much sense to me. Which "named packages" does it list? I see at the end of the command, that there's a `[packages]` argument. Does it list packages mentioned there? This is not clear to me. Several times, I've run `go list` in a go project working directory that has a go.mod and even vendor directory, and all I get is a single output for the current project. The `help` page also states:

```
The default output shows the package import path:

    bytes
    encoding/json
    github.com/gorilla/mux
    golang.org/x/net/html
```

I have no idea what it's talking about here. To me, this is literally a list of 4 completely separate software projects one-after-the-other with no apparent relation.

Please share a better description of what this tool does, specifically which "named packages" it lists, and perhaps some common use-cases and examples of this, as well as any potential side-effects.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-List_packages_or_modules

Answer (score 0):

> Which "named packages" does it list? I see at the end of the command, that there's a [packages] argument. Does it list packages mentioned there?

Yes, the packages are named by the `packages` argument to the command. Run [`go help packages`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns) for information on specifying packages.

> Several times, I've run go list in a go project working directory that has a go.mod and even vendor directory, and all I get is a single output for the current project

The `packages` argument defaults to the package in the current working directory.  The command `go list` prints the import path of the package in the current working directory.

> The default output shows the package import … this is literally a list of 4 completely separate software projects one-after-the-other with no apparent relation.

This part of documentation shows the default output format for some example packages. Use the `[-f format]` or `[-json]` to specify other output formats.

The example output in the documentation is produced by the the command `go list bytes encoding/json github.com/gorilla/mux golang.org/x/net/html`.

Some uses cases:

`go list all`: print import path of the main module and all dependencies.

`go list -f {{.Dir}} github.com/gorilla/mux`: print the directory for the package github.com/gorilla/mux.